# Aa icon for font menu on Android

Tags: android, menu, icons, font-size

I'm looking to add a menu option to change the font size in my Android application. Most applications I've seen that have this option (Kindle reader, Google Books) use an icon like "Aa" to indicate the ability to change the font size, but I can't seem to find a standard icon for this for Android. Is there one? Or am I better off creating my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what you mean but cant think that android have a designated icon, I would advise creating one of your own. It's more fun creating your own anyway.

Comment: Are there examples of people that have created their own? Or other ones I can use, even if not official Android ones?